# How to say $\mathrm{id}_A(x)$

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Given a set $A$, we have the so-called *identity function* which maps each $x\in A$ to $x$ itself:
$$\mathrm{id}_A(x)=x.$$

Since I don't know where else I could ask this question, let me ask it here: How would you *say* "$\mathrm{id}_A(x)$"? Would one say something like "id A of x" or "identity of x" or "the identity function on A of x"?

Comment: I'd probably say "the identity of $A$ at $x$" (however I don't recall if I ever had to use this expression).

Answer (score 1):

If I had to read that out, I'd say, "identity sub A of x".